# Converting string to list in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, list

I have a string in ASP.NET webpage and I want to convert it into list and then convert it into JSON, string had `\n` characters in it I wanted to remove them so I used following code:

```
str.Split(new char[] { '\n'}).ToList();
```

But when I checked my exported JSON it looked as below:

```
{
  "train_statusresult": [
    "Label",
    "",
    "",
    "#",
    "Station",
    "Day",
```

and before I performed split, I looked like this:

```
{
  "train_statusresult": [
    "Label\n\n\n#\nStation",
    "\nDay\n
```

I want to remove `""` quotes which don't have any character between them and want to make JSON well structured. Please help me out.

Comment: "but it is giving me error as \ and n are two characters" - what error? That code should compile fine.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to delete "/n" and eliminate the white space but I'm not able to do so.

Comment: `'\n'` is a single character.

Comment: @ts092: Backslash and n are to characters, but the code you've got is using `\n` as a character literal, representing the *single* character U+000A, which I assumed is the character you want to split. And you still haven't said what error you're getting. It you genuinely have a backslash and an n in your text, you might want to split via a regex. It's not clear what the string really is though... if you're only observing the `\n` in the debugger, that's almost certainly just the newline character being escaped by the debugger. We don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: @ts092: try this str.Split(new string[] { "\n" }).ToList();

Comment: (Also note that "\n" and "/n" are very different. Which have you got?)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am able to split, my bad but I'm not able to eliminate white spaces caused by split.

Comment: So now everything you've asked in the question is irrelevant, but there's another problem which you haven't actually described? Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: What white spaces caused by the split? You *still* haven't described the problem clearly. If you'd provide a short but complete example, with input, expected output and actual output we'd be *far* more able to help you...

Comment: @JonSkeet I have explained the problem I'm facing. Please have a look at question again and see If you can help me out?

Comment: Looks like all you need is `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`

Comment: Can you give me example how can I remove both \n and ""

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question but to split the string and remove the spaces you can use the options:

```
        string MyString = "train_statusresult \n "+Environment.NewLine+" # Station Day";
        var dtList = MyString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\n", " " }, 
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

RemoveEmptyEntries will do what its names says.
If you want the string separated by blank spaces you can add the " " in the list of separators, or you can remove them if you want. Then you can convert it in to JSON and I think the problem would be solved.

Regards!